# React JS Component "wait for props"

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

This is not a question as much "how to make this work" as much as it is a "was this the best way." Here's my code:

```
/**
 * React Static Boilerplate
 * https://github.com/koistya/react-static-boilerplate
 * Copyright (c) Konstantin Tarkus (@koistya) | MIT license
 */

 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 // import './InputWidgetText.scss';
 import ContentBlock from '../ContentBlock';


 var i = 0;
 var contentBlocks = [];

 var ContentContainer = React.createClass({

   addNewBlock: function(){
     i++;
     contentBlocks.push(<ContentBlock key={i} index={i}/>)
     this.forceUpdate();
   },
   render: function(){

     if (this.props.inputs) {
       contentBlocks = this.props.inputs.map(function(item, index){
        i++;
        return(<ContentBlock key={index} index={index} content={item} />)
     });

     }
     return (
       <div>
       {contentBlocks}
       <button onClick={this.addNewBlock}>+</button>
       </div>
       )

   }
 });


 export {ContentContainer as default};
```

The problem is that every so often on a refresh the props.inputs are not getting passed down to this component and throwing an error when I try to map undefined. So the simple solution is to put the map process in an if check for whether or not the props are there yet - is that actually the right way to handle this? My data is passed in via a reflux mixin on the parent. I just feel like there might be a more proper way to handle this. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: You can specify the propTypes on each react component and specify it as `required`. That way, you don't need to check the prop types or if they exist or not. You can read more about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I had to follow the same logic up the chain of parents but then it all worked. Now I just need to get reflux to do a better job sending the data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I strongly suggest you refactor your code to do away with the file variables `i` and `contentBlocks`.

The `contentBlocks` variable seems completely unnecessary, whilst your `i` variable should be part of the *state*. Whilst you're at it, give `i` a more meaningful name, e.g. `blockCount`.

```
getInitialState: function () {
  return {
    blockCount: 0
  };
},
```

Then define your click event handler to modify the state:

```
addNewBlock: function () {
  this.setState({
    blockCount: this.state.blockCount + 1
  });
},
```

Every time you call `setState()`, React will trigger a re-render. You should never need to call `forceUpdate()`.

Finally, your `render()` function should return its content based SOLELY on `this.props` and `this.state`. That is, for any given props and state, the output will be predictable. Think of `this.props` and `this.state` as input parameters to the `render()` function. That is all `render()` can, or needs to, know about.

I won't try to write the `render()` function as I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve with this component. But for a given `this.props.input` and `this.state.blockCount` (or whatever you choose to use as props and state) you should know exactly what you're outputting.

I know I haven't directly answered the question you put, but I hope this clarifies some React concepts.

Comment: well, since I was looking for best practice and you're the only one to write the response as an answer, I guess credit goes to you. Thanks for the refactor tips.